# Получение ближайших элементов в массиве

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Дан двумерный массив:

```
static int[][] multi = new int[][] {
        {2, 0, 4, 1241, 424, 1, 12323},
        {1, 3, 5, 7},
        {321, 320, 32, 41241, -11, -12, -13, -66, -688}
};
```

Нужно создать метод, который принимает индекс определенного элемента и `int range` - количество элементов, находящихся рядом с элементом. Метод должен вернут массив. Например:

`nearby(0, 2, 2)` вернет `2, 0, 1241, 424`

Я сделал что-то вроде:

```
public static int[] nearby(int x, int y, int range) {
    int index = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> leftSize = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> rightSize = new ArrayList();
    while (index != range + 1) {
        leftSize.add(multi[x][y - index]);
        rightSize.add(multi[x][y + index]);
        index += 1;
    }
    leftSize.addAll(rightSize);
    int[] stockArr = new int[leftSize.size()];
    return stockArr;
}
```

Но не уверен, что это лучшее решение.
Какой алгоритм использовать, чтобы работать напрямую с массивом, не создавая `ArrayList`?

Comment: Списки стоит создавать корректно (`new ArrayList<>()`), дабы в будущем не огрести. Копирования из `leftSize` в `stockArr` в вопросе нет - возвращается массив, забитый нулями. Это очень странно

Comment: Если кол-во элементов меньше чем ожидаемый range, что должна вывести программа?

Comment: @Regent ошибочка, исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если опустить проверки границ, то получается так:

```
public static int[] nearby(int x, int y, int range)
{
    int[] result = new int[range * 2];
    System.arraycopy(multi[x], y - range, result, 0, range);
    System.arraycopy(multi[x], y + 1, result, range, range);
    return result;
}
```

Результат:

> [2, 0, 1241, 424]

---

Если при выходе за границы массива дело должно кончаться не `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, а возвратом только допустимых элементов (вплоть до пустого массива), то проще сделать через список:

```
public static int[] nearby(int x, int y, int range)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= multi.length)
        return new int[0];
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = Math.max(y - range, 0); i <= y + range && i < multi[x].length; i++)
    {
        if (i != y)
        {
            result.add(multi[x][i]);
        }
    }
    return result.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).toArray();
}
```

Альтернативным вариантом, с использованием только массивов, тут будет предварительный расчет границ копируемых участков (`leftFirst`, `leftLast`, `rightFirst`, `rightLast`), но восприниматься это будет тяжелее:

```
public static int[] nearby(int x, int y, int range)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= multi.length || y - range >= multi[x].length || y + range < 0)
        return new int[0];
    int leftFirst = Math.max(y - range, 0);
    int leftLast = Math.min(y - 1, multi[x].length - 1);
    int leftLength = leftLast - leftFirst + 1;
    int rightFirst = Math.min(y + 1, multi[x].length);
    int rightLast = Math.min(y + range, multi[x].length - 1);
    int rightLength = rightLast - rightFirst + 1;
    int[] result = new int[leftLength + rightLength];
    System.arraycopy(multi[x], leftFirst, result, 0, leftLength);
    System.arraycopy(multi[x], rightFirst, result, leftLength, rightLength);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Зачем же каждый раз копировать?

Comment: @ИванГладуш что именно вас не устраивает в `System.arraycopy`?

Comment: Он работает безусловно быстро, но мне кажется, что можно написать этот метод каждый раз не копируя и так будет еще быстрее. Ваш метод, безусловно работает верно, но можно написать его так, чтобы он работал еще быстрее.

Comment: @ИванГладуш каким образом он будет работать "ещё быстрее"? Ручное копирование элементов массива с помощью цикла не должно работать быстрее `System.arraycopy`

Comment: Вы правы в том, что ручное копирование работает не быстрее системного, но я и не предлагал копировать в ручную, я предлагаю вообще не копировать.

Comment: @ИванГладуш так вы бы сразу описали что именно вы предлагаете, и мне не пришлось бы угадывать о чём вы говорите

Comment: вы правы, каюсь :)

Answer (score 0):

не хотите `ArrayCopy` - гоняйте циклом. В любом случае, это очень быстрый метод:

```
class PassS {

    static int[][] multi = new int[][]{
        {2, 0, 4, 1241, 424, 1, 12323},
        {1, 3, 5, 7},
        {321, 320, 32, 41241, -11, -12, -13, -66, -688}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nearby(0, 2, 2)));
    }

    public static int[] nearby(int x, int y, int range) {
        int [] stockArr = new int [range*2];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = range-y; i < range+1+y; i++) {
            if (i==range) continue;
            stockArr[count] = multi[x][i];
            count++;
        }
        return stockArr;
    }

}
```